# How to cite in-text same source multiple times (chicago style)?

Tags: writing, writing-style

is there a more economical way of citing something like this:

> In her essay titled “Electronic Literature: What is it?”, N. Katherine Hayles (2007) gives an account of the state of electronic literature. Hayles (2007) maintains [...]

Can I avoid the second in text citation? When do I need to put it back (like different paragraph and so on)?

Comment: What does the style guide of your target journal say?

Comment: @EnergyNumbers no target journal, I'm writing my my dissertation.

Comment: OK, so what does the dissertation style guide for your department / university say? What did you supervisors say? What have other recent theses from your department done?

Comment: I may be missing something here, but can't the second "Hayles(2007)" be replaced by "She"? The context (namely her work) should still be clear.

Comment: This question sounds like one that should be on English SE rather than Academia SE.

Comment: @DCTLib Can you please convert your comment into an answer so that I can vote for it?

Answer (score 1):

There is no necessity to repeat a citation each and every time you refer to the paper. Whenever it is clear from the context to which work you refer to, there is nothing wrong with using words such as "they", "he", or "she" to refer to the author(s) of other works.

For example, you could write:

> In her essay titled “Electronic Literature: What is it?”, N. Katherine Hayles (2007) gives an account of the state of electronic literature. She maintains [...]